# Does Ruunans Hurricane and Twitch ultimate Synergize?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does Ruunans Hurricane work with Twitch ultimate?

Most of the time Ruunans isn't worth it, unless you're running a full on-hit build. I was pondering if it would be useful with Twitch ultimate.

Comment: so you mean if the shots from ruunans also go fullpenetrate and splash poison all over? why not check in a botgame??

Comment: I mean if there is any positive effect at all from ruunans during twitch ulti.

Comment: well that would be the only change that affects twitch's ult i could imagine... play a botgame and build one

Comment: Okay okay, I'll do it when I get home.

Comment: I find Runaan's works best on Twitch for his passive, Ashe for Frost Shot, Caitlyn for stacking her passive faster, and Teemo for obvious reasons.

Comment: Overall Runaan suck though, its damage is too low.

Comment: @Wertilq there's a theorycrafting thread about this going on as we speak, @ http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3171170

Comment: Yea I saw that thread, and that's why I created this question. If you see in the thread I have posted in it :P

Answer (score 4):

[Ruaans hurricane](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Runaan%27s_Hurricane) fires two bolt dealing 10 + 50% AD and **apply on hit affect.**

[twitch](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Twitch) ult gives bonus ad and **changes your basic attack** to a ranged penetrating attack.

So the only the bonus effect that twitch ult will have on ruaans is the increase of ad.
Twitch passive however is a on hit affect and should work.

**EDIT**
From Runaan's Hurricane wiki:

> Twitch will still trigger the effect while  Spray and Pray is active. The two missiles fired are unaffected by the ability, and remain single target, targeted missiles. As such, it is possible for an enemy to be damaged by both Twitch's pass-through attacks and this item.
>
> The Ruaan's bolt range will always stay 300

Comment: Will Ruunans still fire if you use twitch ulti? Does range increase  make Ruunans range longer?

Comment: I edited it, so it should be clear now. Even though Ruaans does really work well with twitch ult I still think its good with his passive.

Comment: Isn't the bolt range same range as auto attack, but with like up to something like 10-20 degree deviation? I have used it on Kogmaw and had it trigger from far longer range than 300.

Comment: Can't find any where that the range of the bolts can increase. its also something that is hard to test in game. Maybe Kog is or was a bug.

Comment: I think what was written on wiki is wrong, it's probably 300 radius from target you shoot at or something like that. I will do some serious testing when I get home.

Comment: Good look with that, I am interested now as well so keep me posted :D.

Comment: Its 300 radius from the target of the attack. Not from the champion. Think of it like a mini buckshot that starts on impact.